# how to get year sequence as i am getting sequence of month only

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdatecomponents

**I have get Sequence of month using following code**

```
NSDate *aDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:row*30*24*60*60  sinceDate:self.earliestPresentedDate];

    NSDateComponents *components = [self.calendar components:(NSEraCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDate *today = [self.calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    components = [self.calendar components:(NSEraCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:aDate];
    NSDate *otherDate = [self.calendar dateFromComponents:components];

    if ([today isEqualToDate:otherDate]) {

    } else {
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        formatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
        formatter.dateFormat = @"MMM ";

        [lblDate setText:[formatter stringFromDate:aDate]];
    }
```

i want to  get Sequence of year how to get...please give solution

Comment: Can you explain more about "After one year"?

Comment: mins i want  jsut like 2015,2016,2017.......

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand. But why don't you do it simple like: +1 to a prev year?

Comment: How about `components.year +=1;`?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and never use something like ´30*24*60*60´. It may work for you and your testcase but time is not as easy at it may look like. Think of other time zones, leap seconds, leap years, dailightsavingtime. always do this via components!

Answer (score 1):

Make one function which gives to date of next year as below,

```
NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    dayComponent.year = +1;

    NSCalendar *theCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *newDate = [theCalendar dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy";
    NSString *strDate = [formatter stringFromDate:newDate];

    NSLog(@"%@",strDate);
```

Set this date in your label.

above I am passing current date so I Will get year : 2016.

Comment: thanks #Kirit Modi can i use  this  code  display year on picker view

Comment: for pickerview, have an array of year.

Comment: yes but i am using above code display month on picker view ....i want display year

Answer (score 0):

Simple way, it logs this and the subsequent 7 years.

```
  NSInteger howManyYears = 8;
  NSInteger thisYear = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] component:NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
  for (NSInteger i = 0; i < howManyYears; ++i) {
    NSLog(@"%ld", thisYear++);
  }
```

or to get an array of strings

```
  NSMutableArray *theYears = [NSMutableArray array];
  NSInteger howManyYears = 8;
  NSInteger thisYear = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] component:NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
  for (NSInteger i = 0; i < howManyYears; ++i) {
    [theYears addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", thisYear++]];
  }
  NSLog(@"%@", theYears);
```